# How I can setup main directory instead web directory to my website in Symfony?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

Actually **I make a clone of a previous site that I have on symfony**. I copy all directory and files on a same server and assign other domain. I can not access to this clone thru the www.domain.com. To view my site I need to do this: **wwww.domain.com/proyect/web/app.php**.

My question is: What I need to do to load my site on principal directory?.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your config of the webpage, e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias domain.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/proyect/web/

        <Directory /var/www/proyect/web/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart apache